У меня при запуске вылезает эта ошибка: TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.surface.Surface, not tuple, подскажите как ее исправить?
У меня при запуске вылезает эта ошибка: TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.surface.Surface, not tuple, подскажите как ее исправить?
ошибка не вылазит если код вот такой:
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:                     
            screen.blit(walk_left[player_anim_count(player_x,player_y))
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:            
        screen.blit(walk_right[player_anim_count(player_x,player_y))

а если добавить вот это то вылезает ошибка
else:
        screen.blit(stay, (player_x, player_y))

пробовал вот это, не помогло
        else:
            screen.blit(stay, (150, 560))


вот тут переменная stay
stay = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Daniil Horosh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\images\195f7dd9-no-bg-HD(carve.photos).png'),

а тут player_x и player_y
player_x = 150
player_y = 560

помогите починить
кстати при запуске должна появляться переменная stay в позиции player_x, player_y
вот по этой  ссылке весь мой код на git hub
https://gist.github.com/dcfcsdcasdsdfsd/51b0e4b50a5d915a4ecbe97c62c5d481

Читай ошибку, переводи, делай выводы. [Ask]

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, не используйте для кода, данных или текста ошибок картинки. См. почему.

я все исправил помогите решить пожалуйста

"а если добавить вот это то вылезает ошибка" - какая ошибка?

TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.surface.Surface, not tuple вот эта ошибка

Проверяйте, что у вас хранится в stay, в вопросе создания этой переменной как раз и нету (откуда она берется и как создается). Ошибка явно указывает, что её тип не подходит, перевод ошибки: аргумент в позиции 1 должен быть типа pygame.surface.Surface, а был передан tuple вместо этого.

И что у вас хранится в walk_left и walk_right, вы уверены, что именно это нужно передавать в screen.blit?

walk_left и walk_right я создал для анимации там фотки в списках а что насчет stay уже исправил в вопросе

Может у вас эта переменная где-то перезаписывается другими данными? Не видя весь код сложно что-то советовать. Освойте логирование и логируйте значения, на которые ругается интерпретатор. И потом смотрите, что там.

ну весь код могу загрузить на git hub и кинуть ссылку но там ОЧЕНЬ много кода ну как по мне

Ну тогда проще будет, если вы при обнаружении ошибки будете куда-то сохранять данные в том месте, где ошибка должна вылезти и анализировать - что там, почему там неправильные данные.

ну чтож я  код на гитхабе загрузил надеюсь мне смогут помочь

А зачем у вас запятая в конце строки stay = pygame.image.load(...),? Уберите её, ошибка из-за этого.

СПАСИБО  я 2 недели искал ответ а проблема в 1 ЗАПЯТОЙ

Питон - язык обманчиво лёгкий, но при этом весьма коварный в некоторых аспектах ))  С помощью лишней запятой всё что угодно легко превращается в кортеж, например.

stay = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\[...].png'),
                                              ^^^ это кортеж!

Лишняя запятая в Питоне превращает любое значение в кортеж. То есть теперь у вас в переменной stay кортеж из одного элемента (да, такое тоже бывает):
stay = (Surface, )

Скобки в Питоне для обозначения кортежа желательны, но не обязательны! Именно запятая либо между элементами кортежа, либо в конце выражения, делает кортеж кортежем, а вовсе не скобки, как можно было подумать, видя кортежи в примерах кода на Питоне.
Так что просто уберите запятую в конце и всё.
